# How can i simplify this using only once math.tan()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I simplify this so I only use math.tan() once?

```
def someTan(x):

return math.tan(x) / (1 - math.tan(x)**2)
```

Comment: Use a variable?

Comment: yh could u help me pls, im quiet noob on this. The variable i used is x

Comment: `a = math.tan(x)`. Now replace `math.tan(x)` by `a` in your formula: `return a / (1 - a*a)`

Answer (score 2):

If you still remember some math, this function is related to `tan(2*alpha)` expansion, it is equivalent to:

```
def someTan(x): return math.tan(2*x)/2
```

Comment: How frustrating _not_ to remember this (from 25 years ago, that said :))

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to simply use a variable that I named `t` like this:

```
def someTan(x):
    t = math.tan(x)
    return (t / (1 - (t**2)))
```